# Display only first level children of my custom taxonomy categories

Tags: custom-taxonomy, advanced-taxonomy-queries

I'd like to display only first level children of my custom taxonomy categories
I'am using wp 3.8

I've something like for my taxonomy "listing_category":
Category 1
  SubCattegoy1
    Subsub category1

I'd like to display only a link to "sub category1" when I'am on "Category 1" (not "subsub category1"). With the code below It displays all sub cat and subsub cat :

```
$taxonomy_name = 'listing_category';
$queried_object = get_queried_object();
$term_id = $queried_object->term_id;
$termchildren = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy_name );
  echo '<ul>';
   foreach ( $termchildren as $child ) {
   $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name );
  echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $child, $taxonomy_name ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
 }
  echo '</ul>';
```

Any ideas to help me ? Thanks

Comment: Have you searched the site? There should be plenty of similar questions available.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code:

```
$taxonomy_name = 'listing_category';
$queried_object = get_queried_object();
$term_id = $queried_object->term_id;

$termchildren = get_terms( $taxonomy_name, array( 'parent' => $term_id, 'hide_empty' => false ) );

echo '<ul>';
   foreach ( $termchildren as $child ) {
       echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $child, $taxonomy_name ) . '">' . $child->name . '</a></li>';
   }
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: Ok, @1fixdotio, many thanks, It is almost perfect ;-)

Comment: Your code list only the first item of the subcategory. In fact (and I think my question was not clear, sorry), I try to list all the subcategories just below the current cat, and just one level below. Any ideas ? My english is not completly fluent ;-)

Comment: Sooory ! It displays only subcategories which contains an item ;-)

Comment: Just updated my code. Set `hide_empty` to `false`, and it will list all sub categories even it contains no post. Let me know I still misunderstood your question.

Comment: Glad it helped. Could you mark my answer as "accepted"? Thanks.